# Чем выполнить JS?

Tags: c#

Средствами POST запроса, от сервера приходит объект JSON.

В одном из значений, JavaScript код - который нужно как то выполнить и получить значение xD

Вот как внутри C# можно выполнить JavaScript ?

Желательно как нибудь без браузеров(

Спасибо!

**UPD**
Библиотека Jint из Nuget решила мою проблему

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643841/how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: @balamutik что то меня оттуда на headless браузеры посылает) другого и более шустрого способа нет ?

Comment: там же есть несколько решений, например - https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net